# Creating element in browser extension inherits browser css?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox extension and one of the things I need to do is adding an element to the dom. I have no problem with this, except that I note that this element inherits some style from xul.css which is something I'd like to avoid (and instead, just use the style the original page uses):

Code is very simple:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
node.appendChild(span)
```

and with firebug I can see that it uses

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    display: -moz-box;
}
```

So how can I make the element not to use the above css?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you created a XUL element, not an HTML element. `document` in your case is a XUL document (that of the browser window?) and the default namespace for elements created is `http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul`. If possible, you should *always* create the elements in the document that they will be inserted into:

```
node.ownerDocument.createElement("span");
```

You could also specify the HTML namespace explicitly:

```
node.ownerDocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "span");
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple stylesheets one can override the other. The above code is a catch all to put a specific styling on all elements in a section or the whole page. Only way to do this is to apply your own styling after you create the span element, preferably display:block;

You can try to remove the styling with the following jquery script after you create it

```
span.setAttribute('id',"MyElement");
$('#MyElement').removeClass('*');
```

OR you will have to over ride it with

---

```
span.setAttribute('id',"MyElement");
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "predifinedClass";
```

or jquery

```
span.setAttribute('id',"MyElement");
$('#MyElement').addClass('MyClass');
----- OR -----
$('#MyElement').css('display','block'); // to specify 1 css rule
```

Comment: `xul.css` is one of browser's built-in stylesheets. The question isn't about overriding it, it's about not having it apply in the first place.